# Responsive website design, navbar won't centre correctly when resized to phone dimensions

Tags: html, css, iphone, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm in the process of making my portfolio website for my senior year, and I can't seem to get the navbar (Work About Contact) to centre when it's in mobile mode. I realistically want it to sit underneath the logo, completely centered, but nothing seems to be working.

I've tried to make another div around the navbar div, and giving that margins of 0 auto 0 auto, as well as the navbar div alone, but that isn't working either.

Take a look and please let me know what you think.

http://alinewbury.com/responsive.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you missed to specify `text-align: center;` in you `.navbar` (add it to line 63 of your css file)

Comment: You are very welcome! just mark (check) the answer as correct